# Why this jquery code is not working for me?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote very samll code in jquery, but i am unable execute it  Where i am wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js">    
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help will be greatly appriciated.

Comment: Check your javascript console. See if there are any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to close script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"> </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to close your script tag for jquery. It should be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('p').click(function() {
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Notice the closing `</script>` tag

Answer (score 3):

You did not close the first script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Close the script tag inside the head tag.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js">  </script>   
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
   });
  });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
</body>

</html>
```